# c++ C2440 error cannot convert from 'const BWAPI::UpgradeType' to 'const BWAPI::Type *'

Tags: c++, inheritance, syntax-error

error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'const BWAPI::UpgradeType' to 'const BWAPI::Type *'

at this line

```
this->generalType = type;
```

what is the problem? since UnitType extends Type shouldn't be permitted?

```
class CombatEvent {

public:
    CombatEvent& setUnitType(const UnitType& type);
    const Type* getGeneralType() const;

private:
    UnitType unitType;
    const Type* generalType;
}

// implementation

CombatEvent& CombatEvent::setUnitType(const UnitType& type) {

    this->generalType = type;
    this->unitType = type;

    return *this;
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to take the address:

```
this->generalType = &type;
```

Comment: but when i do setUnitType(const UnitType& type) the & isn't already passing the reference??

Comment: The problem is that `const UnitType& type` is a **reference** and `CombatEvent::generalType` is a **pointer**. You can't assign a reference to pointer.

Answer (score 0):

You're assigning a reference to a pointer. Correct code:

```
this->generalType = &type;
```

You may have a look at these links

[References vs. Pointers](http://eetimes.com/discussion/programming-pointers/4023307/References-vs-Pointers)

[What are the differences between pointer variable and reference variable in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-pointer-variable-and-reference-variable-in-c)

Comment: but when i do setUnitType(const UnitType& type) the & isn't already passing the reference??

Answer (score 0):

There's a fundamental problem in your use of BWAPI Types.

**1.** BWAPI::Type is a templated class that contains all the utility functions common among all types. There is no need to use it. There is no way to know if it is a UnitType or UpgradeType, it only contains an integer as the underlying type.

**2.** There is no need to turn BWAPI Types into pointers or references. The compiler resolves it to an integer, nothing fancy about it. Would you use `const int&` everywhere in your code?